# JS filter/autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a search field on my site to have an autocomplete/filter function based off of strings in a JSON object. I want to treat the search box as a way to filter out anything that could be in the JSON object.

Here's the search bar in html:

```
<form id="searchProducts">
<input type="text" class="md-input label-fixed" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" autofocus placeholder="Search Products"/>
<span class="md-input-bar"></span>
</form>
```

And here's the JS for the JSON object, created from a php array:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var orderFormData = <?php Json_encode ($tempdata);?>;
</script>
```

I'm not sure the best function to use or how to use it on the JSON object, but I've heard JS autocomplete may be a good solution.

Is there a pretty straightforward way to tie these together and have a nice autocomplete/filter function on my search?

Comment: i got busty... i was going to try to use this library to see if it would work for you: http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#download but haven't had time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just given as a proof-of-concept:

```
<form id="searchProducts">
<input type="text" class="md-input label-fixed" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" autofocus placeholder="Search Products"/>
<span class="md-input-bar"></span>
</form>
<script>
  var orderFormData = <?php Json_encode ($tempdata);?>;
</script>
<script>
  var orderData = orderFormData // default value
  var search = function (e) {
    var term = e.currentTarget.value     
    orderData = Object.entries(orderFormData).reduce(function (data, entry) {
      if (entry[0].match(term) || entry[1].match(term)) {
        data[entry[0]] = entry[1]
      }

      return data
   }, {})

   console.log(orderData)
  }

  document.querySelector('#srch-term').addEventListener('keyup', search)    
</script>
```

This handles the filter part, based on the a match from key/value to the term given in the input.

If you want the autocomplete, then you will have to code much more :)

Comment: I actually would rather have just filter, no autocomplete. However, I formatted this into my code and there's something missing. So, everything from orderformdata is loaded on the page, so If I enter a match then I want the matched items only showing on the page, but it doesn't seem to change anything on the page. the console says that my entry doesn't match certain indeces, but I'm seeing the text on the screen. I'm going to have to play with it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `echo`:

```
<?php echo json_encode($tempdata);?>;
```

When you are using `json_encode`, you need to `echo` or `print()`. Also make sure you use the right case (optional).

Comment: Thank you I added that now. I still need some assistance with the filter/autocomplete option but that should help

Comment: @TomN. Sure, what's up?